# Using Java Generics without a type - Generic erasure?

Tags: java, generics

Take a look at this method:

```
public class Outer<E> {
    public static class Inner{
        public E value;
        public Inner(E value){
            this.value = value;
        }
     }
}
```

We'll use it using this code:

```
Outer.Inner i = new Outer.Inner(5);
System.out.println(i.value);
```

This thing won't compile becuase E is used in the inner method.

My question is - I know that at compile time all the generics are erased and replaced by Object.
So why isn't this the case here? E would be replaced by Object and this whole thing should compile.

Does this mean that we can never use Generic classes without the type? (I know that this is bad practice, but I assumed that this should work)

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't compile because your inner class is `static`.  The type of `E` depends on an _instance_ of the `Outer` class, and so a `static` `Inner` class has no concept of what `E` is for itself.
Making the `Inner` class non-static, and creating one via `new Outer().new Inner(5)` should allow you to do what you're trying here.

Comment: "*I know that at compile time all the generics are erased and replaced by Object. So why isn't this the case here?*"  They would erased, if you made it to runtime. That doesn't mean the compiler will let you do anything you want. The whole point of generic is to enforce a compile-time constraint. The compiler is trying to enforce those constraints, but you've used them in an illegal way such that it can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with type erasure. This is simply because you can't use type parameters in any static declarations. As the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2) says:

> It is a compile-time error to refer to a type parameter of a generic
>   class C in any of the following:
>
> - the declaration of a static member of C (§8.3.1.1, §8.4.3.2, §8.5.1).
> - the declaration of a static member of any type declaration nested
>     within C.
> - a static initializer of C (§8.7), or
> - a static initializer of any class declaration nested within C.

The first point applies here.

So not even this will compile:

```
class Foo<T> {
    public static void f(T param) {}
}
```